# How to run a makefile? Absolute beginner

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to run a makefile which does some stuff.
I am on windows (64) and was told to download and install GNU make and use the command "make" in command-line while in the appropriate directory.
I get "make is not recognized.." etc error.

I couldn't find any information regarding the basics and feel like I'm doing something incredibly stupid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to figure out where `make` got installed to and add it to your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add the location of `make.exe` to your path (you didn't say which version of Windows, but in Win7 it's `Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environmental Variables`, and add to `PATH`), or fully qualify the path in your command-line entry:

```
c:\YourFolder\>"C:\<Path to GNU Make>\make.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

If make is installed and setup correctly then likely you just need to add the directory in which make is located to your environment path. To do this in Windows you need to go to the System Properties and then on the Advanced tab is a button at the bottom called "Environment Variables". For the "User variables..." you will either edit the current "PATH" variable if it already exist or create a new variable called "PATH" if it does not exist. The value is just a list of directories to be included in the path, each separated with a semicolon.